# Jquery Click event doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, slidetoggle

The following code is a drop down login box. The link appears but isn't clickable. As I MouseOver it, it doesnt recognize it as a link but as simple text. Cliking doesnt fire anything neither.

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-link").click(function(){
        $("#login-panel").slideToggle(200);
    })
})
```

The html :

```
<a id='login-link' href='#login' title='Login'>Connexion</a>
<div id='login-panel'>
</div>
```

The Css :

```
#login-link{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

#login-panel{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 2px;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    font-size: 7pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Note:** I applied a `event.preventDefault()` on others items but there's no reason that it inherited from it in any way ...

Comment: Actualy it works fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/HyVHB/)

Comment: @Molecule: Beat me to it :). Duke: What browser are you using? It's working fine here on Chrome

Comment: I'm on chrome too ... still didn't sort it out

Comment: Well what behaviour does the fiddle Molecule posted not give you? If I hover over the element at the top right, I get the hand icon (http://i51.tinypic.com/25gxcol.jpg), and if I click it, an empty box slides down (http://i54.tinypic.com/2vv57yr.jpg). Click the element again slides the empty box up.

Comment: Just a guess, semicolons are missing at the end of 2 last lines, after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Maxi ^ http://aresemicolonsnecessaryinjavascript.com/